# Adding images to nodes in a d3.js graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I'm currently trying to add images from an API call to a force directed graph in D3.js but currently my graph isnt displaying any nodes. Im able to load all the image URL's into the variable called image but it wont display them. Can anybody see where Im going wrong?

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(json.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag)
      .on('dblclick', reDirect)
      .on('mouseover', connectedNodes)
      .on('mouseout', allNodes)
      .on('contextmenu', function(d){d3.event.preventDefault();tip.show(d);})  //.on('mousedown', tip.show)
    .on('mouseleave', tip.hide)  //.on('mouseup', tip.hide)
      ;

  node.append("img")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.degree;})
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d) { return d.image;}) 
    .attr("x", "60")
    .attr("y", "60")
    .attr("width", "20")
    .attr("height", "20")                   

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 3)           //It means the offset of label and circle
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name })
      .style("font-size",function(d) { return d.degree*2+'px' })
      .style("stroke", "gray");  

 force.on("tick", function() {

    var radius = 10;

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x)) + "," + Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y)) + ")"; });

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  });
```

Here is the fuctions to generate the nodes:

```
function callNodes(node) {
                    $.get("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/" + node + "/top-answerers/all_time?site=stackoverflow", function (data) {
                        allRelatedNodes = data["items"];
                        setNodes(allRelatedNodes, node);
                    });

                }

                  function setNodes(allNodes, node) {               
                    featureContent = { nodes:[{name: node,group:0,degree:20}],links:[]};                    
                    for (var i = 0; i < allNodes.length; i++) {
                        var colorRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 18) + 1;
                        var name = allNodes[i].user.display_name;
                        var image = allNodes[i].user.profile_image;
                        console.log(image);
                        var newNode = {'name': name, 'group': colorRandom, 'degree': 10, 'userImage': image};
                        var newLink = {'source': 0, 'target': i+1, 'color': 5};
                        featureContent.nodes.push(newNode);
                        featureContent.links.push(newLink);
                    }

                    d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
                    featureGraph(featureContent,900,700,0,"#graph",200,-200);
                }
```

Comment: Your node property naming seems off: `var newNode = {... 'image': image};`
or `.attr("xlink:href",function(d) { return d.userImage;}) `

Comment: Hmm that is true still not correcting the graph.